# Is django's ORM thread safe?

Tags: django, multithreading, thread-safety, django-orm

I have a python program which uses django's ORM for db access. The program has various threads, each could potentially access the db with either reads or writes. Notice this program is not a web server.

Is django's ORM thread safe?
Can it be used in parallel from different threads in the same interpreter?
Does the answer depend on the transaction management mode? django version? anything else?

Comment: From what I understand the thread safety [is ensured](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5.5/django/db/backends/__init__.py#L141) by using transactions, which starting from 1.6, is enabled [by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django-s-default-transaction-behavior). So in django <1.6 it is only when you apply transactions manually.

Comment: It likely will depend on your database driver.  I'd venture that most are *not* thread safe.

Comment: it's incredible to me that such a basic question doesn't have a clear and well documented answer

Comment: I found in [the caveat section of django 1.6's Persistent Connections feature documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#caveats) the following text: `Since each thread maintains its own connection, your database must support at least as many simultaneous connections as you have worker threads.` which if I understand correctly, may shed a bit of light and give some hope...

Comment: Django is a web application framework. Thread-safety is not something that's high on the agenda as each web worker will have its own thread. You'd better have a look at other ORM's that advertise thread-safety. Or, you could write your code in a way that doesn't require thread-safety.

Comment: It's thread-safe because it automagically creates a new connection for each thread, even if the database driver has thread-safe connection objects. It defeats the point of threading if you use it to share a single connection between threads.

Answer (score 7):

Yes,

Methods query, filter, get, exclude, etc. Return a new QuerySet object so the fundamental is done and you will get no problems doing Queries in a thread as it will always return a new object with no past references.

Disable the autocommit setup. You may be using more often transactions and the select_related method to avoid common thread problems like accessing rows at the same time.

I recommend you that always check your code will return a new QuerySet object and do not send querysets as arguments in functions and you will be Ok.

Comment: why to disable the default auto commit setup? when should I commit the queries?

Comment: "Do not send querysets as arguments in functions" :O That's all my (legacy) application does :D